# SQL to list missing partition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

The SQL below list the partitions for a partitioned table

```
select partition_name
from   dba_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'ABCD'
order by partition_name
;


PARTITION_NAME
------------------------------
P_201511
P_201512
P_201601
P_201602
P_201603
P_201604
P_201605
P_201606
P_201607
P_201608
P_201609
P_201610
P_201611
P_201612
P_201701
P_201702
P_201703
P_201704
P_201705
P_201706
P_201707
P_201708
P_201709
P_201710
P_201711
P_201712
P_201801
P_201802
P_201803
P_201804
P_201805
P_201806
P_201807
P_201808
P_201809
P_201810
P_201811
P_201812
P_201901
P_201902
P_201903
P_201904
P_201905
P_201906
P_201907
P_201908
P_201909
P_201910
P_201911
P_202207
P_202208
P_202209

52 rows selected.
```

As you can see the partitions 201912 to 202206 are missing. Does anyone knows any SQL trick that will able to list the missing partitions maybe on a second field  or maybe list the missing partition in bracket so it list it like below for sample

```
P_201909
P_201910
P_201911
[P_201912]
[P_202001]
[P_202002]
...
...
[P_202205]
[P_202206]
P_202207
P_202208
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     -- min and max dates from partition names for the ABCD table
  3     period (min_date, max_date)
  4     AS
  5        (SELECT MIN (TO_DATE (SUBSTR (partition_name, 3), 'yyyymm')),
  6                MAX (TO_DATE (SUBSTR (partition_name, 3), 'yyyymm'))
  7           FROM dba_tab_partitions
  8          WHERE table_name = 'ABCD'),
  9     all_partitions (partition_name)
 10     -- create all possible partition names between MIN and MAX date
 11     AS
 12        (    SELECT 'P_' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (min_date, LEVEL - 1), 'yyyymm')
 13               FROM period
 14         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN (max_date, min_date) + 1)
 15    -- finally, outer join generated partition names to "real" partition names and
 16    -- set indicator for missing partitions
 17    SELECT a.partition_name || CASE WHEN d.partition_name IS NULL THEN '*' END partition_name
 18      FROM all_partitions a
 19           LEFT JOIN dba_tab_partitions d
 20              ON     d.partition_name = a.partition_name
 21                 AND d.table_name = 'ABCD'
 22  ORDER BY a.partition_name;
```

---

```
PARTITION_NAME
--------------------
P_201511
P_201512
P_201601
P_201602
P_201603
<snip>
P_201909
P_201910
P_201911
P_201912*
P_202001*
P_202002*
P_202003*
P_202004*
P_202005*
P_202006*
<snip>
P_202202*
P_202203*
P_202204*
P_202205*
P_202206*
P_202207
P_202208
P_202209

83 rows selected.

SQL>
```